# d3 stacked bar chart issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

For an assignment that is based on d3 js, we tried to implement the stacked bar chart, from this link http://bl.ocks.org/mstanaland/6100713 . The issue is that only the first element of our var `dataset` gets the correct values for `y0` and `y`, the second element `Earthquake` gets value NaN for `y` and sometimes positive values for `y0`. If we give a fixed level for `y`, the chart stacks correctly and have the correct colors etc.

Anyone that could help?

Our current code is posted below:

```
  var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(naturalDisasters.map(function(nd) {

    return data.map(function(d) {

      return {x: parse(d.Year), y: +d[nd], y0: 0 };

    });
  }));
```

The variable `naturalDisasters` is a variable with 9 categories of natural disasters

```
var naturalDisasters = ["Drought", "Earthquake", "Epidemic", 
"ExtremeTemperature", "ExtremeWeather", "Flood", "Landslide", 
"VolcanicActivity", "Wildfire"];
```

data is an array with 118 objects {Year: ..., Drought: "2", Earthquake: "0", ....}

The goal is to create the variable dataset with values for `x`, `y`, `y0` corresponding to the example stated above.

Comment: Log `d`, `nd` and `+d[nd]` to console inside that function to see what is there.

Answer (score 0):

The key first step is getting the data formatted correctly. Here's what I learned after 2 day struggle with my stacked area chart using d3 v3.

1. Before transforming and formatting the data sort it based on the x axis element.
2. As you transform the data make sure every x item has ALL y items even if the value is 0.